# Gnu debugger can't remove variable from display?

Tags: c++, g++, gnu

I am working on a c++ program on linux ubuntu 16.04 and I've done a tutorial on gnu debugger.

I am having some problems with my code and as I step through it it's easier for me to compare two variables at each part `fullPath` and `argv[1]`

But once I get past that particular segment I want to remove `argv[1]`.

I called them with the following:

> display argv[1]
>
> display fullPath

But when I try to remove `argv[1]` with `undisplay argv[1]` I get an error that reads the following:

> warning: bad display number at or near 'argv[1]'

It still continues to display `argv[1]` unless I exit debugger and start it again without displaying it. Is there a way to fix this?

NOTE
I've also tried `delete argv[1]` which also doesn't work.

Comment: I don't believe that this should be a duplicate because undisplaying by counter is not discussed there. It only points to documentation and mentions the undisplay option exists

Comment: The answer you upvoted and the duplicate say **exactly** the same thing. You cannot agree with the answer and claim, that an identical Q&A is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `undisplay` command is expecting a list number, not an expression.  You can see the list numbers for all your auto-display expressions by typing:

```
info display
```

Let's say that `argv[1]` is assigned item 3 in that list.  You would then remove it with:

```
undisplay 3
```

Comment: Tested this and it works awesomely. Have an upvote